# window.print prints 3 copies

Tags: javascript, printing

I'm going mad, please help me.

I simply need to print a ticket using window.print command...but without explanation the printer prints three copies of the ticket.

this is my code:

```
    function printTicket(number){
        document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML = number;
        $('#MyModal').modal('show');
        setTimeout(function () {
               printElement(document.getElementById("printThis"));
        }, 500);

    $('#MyModal').modal('hide');    
    return true;
}


function printElement(elem) {
    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);

    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");

    if (!$printSection) {
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }

    $printSection.innerHTML = "";
    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
    window.print();
}
```

the printer settings is correctly set to print one copy

and this is the modal dialog to print

```
<div id="printThis">
<div id="MyModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

    <!-- Modal Content: begins -->
    <div class="modal-content">


      <!-- Modal Body -->  
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="body-message">
          <table id="Table_02" width="170" height="283" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr><td><img src="img/images/numeretto_new_01.jpg" width="170" height="169" alt=""></td></tr>
          <tr><td><div style="font-size:100px; text-align:center" id="num2"></div></td></tr>
          <tr><td><img src="img/images/numeretto_new_03.jpg" width="170" height="37" alt=""></td></tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>
    <!-- Modal Content: ends -->

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The action starts when the last form's field loses the focus

```
 <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" value="" autocomplete="off"  class="formTS" style="top:235px; left:-57px" onChange="insertCue()">
```

the function insertCue() call a PHP via ajax that returns a number to print

```
function insertCue() {

    var userName = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var userSurname = document.getElementById('surname').value;
    var userCF = document.getElementById('cf').value;



     var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();    

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    printTicket(xmlhttp.responseText);

                 }

             }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "insertCue.php?userName="+userName+"&userSurname="+userSurname+"&userCF="+userCF, true);
        xmlhttp.send();



}
```

Comment: Sounds like someone is binding the event multiple times.

Comment: Yes, but what? There's only one window.print command!!

Comment: Show how you call `printTicket`, that is most likely the problem. You do not show that in your code.

Comment: I edited the questions with more details and the infos you request me.

Comment: So start adding code to debug it and see what is being triggered more than once. `console.log()` is your friend here.